# onTouch() not triggering

Tags: java, android, ontouch

I found out that the Android onTouch event won't be triggered when I stop moving my finger on the screen, so I can't get my pointer count for every tick of my game correctly.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
    pointerCount = e.getPointerCount();
}
```

Does anyone have a solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

```
sound1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    pressed1 = true;
    mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(MainClass.this, R.raw.item1);
    mp1.start();
    sound1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pad_pressed);
    if (looping == true) {
        mp1.setLooping(true);
    } else if (looping == false) {
        mp1.setLooping(false);
    }
    return true;

} else if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
    pressed1 = false;
    mp1.stop();
    mp1.reset();
    mp1.release();
    sound1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pad_normal);
    return true;
}
return false;
  }});
```